# Need to stretch width of items in HorizontalScrollView->LinearLayout to fill HorizontailScrollView

Tags: android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I am brand-new to Android development, so please bear with me. :-)  I have created a HorizontalScrollView (android:fillViewport="true"), containing a LinearLayout (android:alignmentMode="alignBounds", android:orientation="horizontal") which in turn contains a series of Button (android:layout_width="fill_parent",               android:layout_height="wrap_content", android:layout_gravity="center") objects.  When I run the app, it behaves as one would expect, allowing me to scroll horizontally between the buttons, like so:

[narrow buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOSq8.png)

What I would like to do, however, is to stretch the width of each Button so that it corresponds to the width of the HorizontalScrollView (and scrolling between buttons still works), like so:

[wide buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xe6n.png)

In other words, I would like to match the width of each button to that of its *grandparent*.  Is this possible?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you want each button to be centered when you scroll horizontally? I mean, you can only see one button at a time? You can use a ViewPager for that

Comment: Ah, I was under the wrong impression that ViewPager widget were for flipping thru entire pages/screens.  Thanks!

Comment: Also found 2 other approaches: (1) ensuring that the layout_width of each element added to the LinearLayout is exactly the same as the layout_width of the HorizontalScrollView and (2) Subclassing the LinearLayout and overriding onMeasure() and measureChildWithMargins() to stretch the client area (and assign equal weights to each added element) so that only one element can appear at a time. I'm presently using (1) and do not recommend (2).  I'll look into the ViewPager approach, though.  Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I hope the ViewPager works for you. You can flip through views with it, doesn't have to be only screens.